# how to join two separate table(not child table ) in firebase using id?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new in firebase Environment .I have firebase database as follows

[image: image of two firebase table]

I have two firebase table named as customer and booking where i want to do join operation using cloud function. In the booking table there is row named as **customerId** which corresponds to the **uid** of customer table. I want to do a join operation between them and show the joined table. Any help is appreciated 
 I have tried the following code:

```
exports.join = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
        response.header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
          if (request.method === 'OPTIONS') {
         response.status(204).send('');
       }
    var booking=admin.database().ref().child('booking');
    var customer=admin.database().ref().child('booking');

    booking.on('child_added',function(snap){
    console.log(snap.val());

    customer.child(snap.val().uid).once('value',user =>{
    console.log(user.val());

   response.status(200).json({ booking: snap.val(),customer: user.val() });

    });
   // response.status(200).json({ order: snap.val(),user: user.val() });

    });

});
```

---

I modified the above code . and write the function as follows:

```
exports.join2 = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    res.header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');

    //respond to CORS preflight requests
    if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
        res.status(204).send('');
    }
    var booking = admin.database().ref().child('booking');
    var customer = admin.database().ref().child('customer');

    customer.on('child_added', function (snap) {
        var uid = snap.val().uid; // line 1 (results like 1,2,3,4,5,6)
        console.log(uid);


        booking.orderByChild('customerId').equalTo(uid).on('value', function (snapshot) {
            // customer.orderByChild('uid').equalTo(userId).once('value', function(snapshot) {
            console.log(uid + "-------------------------------------->");
            console.log(snapshot.val());
            res.status(200).json({ customer: snap.val(), booking: snapshot.val() });

        });
    });
});
```

The data returning in the console is fine but when I returned the response as json object it only return first object that is first customer along with their  booking details and I am unable to return as all customer data with their booking.
Any suggestion .

Comment: Please share what you've tried so far

Comment: i have tried this code in firebase cloud function

Answer (score 2):

To load the customer by their UID with your current data structure, you'll need to do:

```
var customers=admin.database().ref().child('customer');
customers.orderByChild('uid').equalTo(uid).once('value', function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(customerSnapshot) {
    console.log(customerSnapshot.key, customerSnapshot.val());
  });
});
```

Having to query to look up a user by their UID is an anti-pattern though. It's better to store each user under their UID in the JSON:

```
customers
  uid1: ...
  uid2: ...
```

With that structure the above code can be simplified to:

```
var customers=admin.database().ref().child('customer');
customers.child(uid).once('value', function(snapshot) {
  console.log(customerSnapshot.key, customerSnapshot.val());
});
```

Not only is this code simpler, it also scales a lot better, since you don't have to do a query for each user.

This is just one of the many problems with your current code though. Instead of covering each problem (and essentially writing the entire solution to your use-case for you), I recommend that you first read the [Firebase documentation for Web developers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start) and take the [Firebase codelab for Web developer](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/). They cover many basic JavaScript, Web and Firebase interactions. After that use the Admin SDK in a local Node.js process, which can be debugged with a local debugger. After those you'll be much better equipped to write code for Cloud Functions.